# Japan vs the percentage in Japan

Tags: grammar, participle-clauses

Since what hovers is the percentage and not the country, I wonder if I have to start the second clause with "the percentage" and not "Japan".

> Hovering between 3% and 7%, **Japan** has had a lower percentage of
> people aged 65 and over than the other two countries.

> Hovering between 3% and 7%, **the percentage** of people aged 65 and
> over has been lower in Japan than in the other two countries.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct.

The first sentence is correct because it is correct and natural to say, "Japan hovers between 3% and 7% (in percentage of people aged 65 and over)."

The second sentence, of course, is also correct because 3-7% is a percentage.